# Как правильно настроить правку даты и времени в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть текстовые поля, в которых заносится дата и время при запуске формы.

Как реализовать исправление по кусочкам чтобы, при нажатии на год, день или час можно было редактировать только выделенное число, без возможности удаления тире или двоеточия?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то, что вы описываете, похоже на masked text box - хз как он в формах называется. Вот [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) похоже

Comment: Используйте родной `DateTimePicker` вместо текстбокса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый способ. Используйте элемент `DateTimePicker`, который позволяет выбрать дату и время и отобразить их в указанном формате. Как установить нужный формат смотрите [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat(v=vs.110).aspx).

Второй способ - это использование `MaskedTextBox`, он позволяет создать шаблон, по которому будут вводиться данные. Также можно настроить валидацию вводимых данных. [Подробнее на метаните](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.4.php).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваш ответ решил проблему, но теперь возникла другая: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846559/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-datagridview