# Как изменить формат даты и времени в таблице dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Если короче, то как сделать, чтобы формат **timestamp** в dataGridView был таким же, как в MySQL?

Имеется несколько столбцов таблицы MySQL с типом данных **timestamp**. При отображении результата запроса с помощью dataGridView столбцы с датами меняют свой формат на какой-то другой. Как сделать так, чтобы формат даты и времени в dataGridView не менялся??

Вот как выглядит дата и время в MySQL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как он выгружается в TextBox при выборе записи из ячейки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Мне нужно будет сравнить дату размещения с другой датой, которая указывается ниже, но я не могу их сравнить, т.к. их форматы отличаются, а если я запишу другую дату в том же формате, что и вверху, то сравнение получится, но, при отправлении даты возникнит ошибка, мол формат не тот.

Что-то типа этого не помогает. Пишет мол "Индекс вышел за рамки диапазона"

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Преобразуйте в запросе дату в строку нужного формата. Строка придёт клиенту и отобазится один в один, как нужно.

Comment: @Akina, и снова благодарю вас!

Comment: @Akina Глупость советуешь. Ему не отобразить нужно, а сравнить две даты. А ты предлагаешь вместо сравнения дат сравнивать строки

Comment: _Индекс вышел за рамки диапазона_ - полагаю, формат задаётся до привязки данных. А нужно это делать после.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, строки тоже подойдут. У меня они в отдельной функции преобразовываются в даты и сравниваются. Да, от этого страдает оптимизация, но я не придумал, как сравнивать даты без преобразования в строки и обратно. Такой вот я дилетант((
Страховка на уровне ReadOnly = true;

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью функции DATE_FORMAT. Формат в ковычках совпадает с **timestamp** и данные в Data Grid View отображаются точно также, а не меняются.

```
string Query = "select DATE_FORMAT (placement_date, '%Y-%m-%d %T') from Orders;"
MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(Connection); //ну и дальше еще код
```

Giving credits to Akina!